# Outlining #IF-#ELSE C/C++ code block in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there is anyway way to outline the #IF-#ELSE-#ENDIF code block in VS Code for C/C++ language? Sometimes there are too many nested #IF-#ELSE code blocks to know what code belongs to what code block when reading other's code.

There is such feature in [SlickEdit](https://community.slickedit.com/index.php?topic=574.0) and [VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669124/outlining-if-else-code-block-in-visual-studio-2010). Anybody know how to enable it in VS Code? Is it provided by an extension? Thanks.

Sorry I can't post an image to show the effect due to lacking enough reputation. Will add it once I can.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by outlining `if` blocks? Do you mean folding? What language are you using? As a side note if you have more than 2 nested `if` statements you should refactor your code to be more inclusive and not have to deal with edge cases.

Comment: @Burgi: No point of downvoting answers - a comment is enough. pansila: what are you really asking about?

Comment: @harrymc voting is anonymous. You cannot assume that it was me.

Comment: @Burgi I'm using C/C++ and I'm reading some code written by someone else so how to organize the code is out of topic. By outlining #IF-#ELSE code blocks I mean highlighting the nearest matching #IF and #ELSE lines if the cursor is in the code block between #IF and #ELSE.

Comment: @harrymc You can check out the feature in the links I provided in the description above. Other matured editors have it already for a long time.